# How to test a method with local instance?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Imagine the following class:

```
class ClassToBeTested{
    private IClassA a;
    private IClassB b;

    public ClassToBeTested(IclassA a, IClassB b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void MethodToBeTested()
    {
         //...
         var c = new ClassC(a, b);
         c.doSomeThing();
         //...
    }
}
```

And I want to do some unit tests for `MethodToBeTested`. But I can't find a way to moq `ClassC` object without doing dependency injection. I don't want to change the method signature and pass `ClassC` as parameter.

Is there way to unit test this method?

Comment: You could make a virtual method that returns a `ClassC` and that would be mockable. See [Testing the Un-Testable](https://contrivedexample.com/2016/11/26/testing-the-un-testable/)

Comment: you can do property injection and create a property of type `ClassC` in yout `ClassToBeTested`

Comment: Use dependency injection but if you do not want to do that and you have access to VS Enterprise you can use fakes and fake ClassC and it's members. This is handy when you do not have source control over a Type that is being used. In your case though I would recommend DI. If you are testing and it is not easy because of tightly coupled classes then you need to refactor, (the test is telling you your design needs to change)

Comment: Why are you (basically) injecting `IclassA` and `IclassB`, but not `ClassC`?

Comment: @KennethK. Why would I inject `ClassC` when I can create it. It does not seem redundant for you?

Comment: Because you don't understand dependency injection.

Comment: as long as `class C` uses `IClassA` and `IClassB`, why would you need to inject or mock `class c`? You need to mock `IClassA` and `IClassB`, and that should be enough. Although to be clear, your tests will be more complicated and the design is bad.

Comment: @AD.Net that is assuming `ClassC` has no significant behavior of its own.

Comment: @Crowcoder ClassC needs to have its own unit tests

Comment: @SirRufo unit tests don't preclude the need to mock behavior. I believe AD .Net is correct, but I don't want to mislead OP. We can't see the implementation and it is possible this is not the best advice.

Answer (score 1):

Either inject in `ClassC` in to `ClassToBeTested` or if you depend on creating it at runtime, inject in some kind of Factory say `ClassCFactory` then you can mock out the factory instead.